# How to make a NSString always use fixed font width

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, font-size

I want to have an `NSString` in the format "hh:mm:ss" to use exactly the same amount of pixel space as the string "88:88:88". Is that possible?

Now I'm using:

```
// ... 
NSMutableString * strS = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", Seconds];
if (Seconds<10){
  [strS insertString:@"0" atIndex:0];
}

// Make the time to show
[ClocklLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2@:%2@:%2@", strH,strM,strS]];
```

with no success!

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for a [monospaced font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Try using Courier for example:

```
UIFont *courier = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:12.0f];
label.font = courier;
```

If you're trying to create a digital clock display, you could also simply use a separate label for each number and position the labels however you want.

Comment: @JohnWilund, please accept the most helpful answer. it takes just a click.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a monospace font. If you do not want this, use a `UILabel` and set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to YES. However, in this case the height will vary.

Comment: I do this as well as a mono-spaced font.

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question hints to the fact that you are missing an important detail. `NSString` only contains the actual text.

It is not the `NSString` that dictates font, color or other attributes. As other answers have suggested you should set the font to the label/textfield/button or whatever visual gadget is supposed to display the string.

If you want to combine both text and text attributes, you may want to check `NSAttributedString`.